# Javascript: Array declaration - derived from textbook studies

Tags: arrays

I have a specific question.  I was studying from my JavaScript book.  It gives an example of an array object.  I am questioning how my book says to call it.

```
    var people = [
        { name: 'Casey', rate: 70, active: true},
        { name: 'John', rate: 130, active: true},
        { name: 'Jodie', rate: 125, active: false},
        { name: 'Bettie', rate: 80, active: true}
    ]
```

They say to call it like:

```
    person[1].name;
    person[1].rate;
```

Which would return:

```
    John 130
```

My question is: Isn't there a step missing?  How does JavaScript know that person[] is supposed to be an array of people[]?  Did the textbook fail to say that a person[] array needs to be declared for people[]?  Am I missing something?  How does person[] get connected to people[]?  Does it intuitively know?  Yes, I'm a newbie.  Should there be a declaration as follows:

var person[] = people[];

I know that looks bad, but how does person get anything from people when person was never declared?  Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is either a step missing here or there's a chance it could be a typo in the book. But your intuition is correct. JavaScript has no sense of the English language so it does not know that a group of persons may be referred to as people.

Comment: To spell it out a little more clearly, your book probably meant to say `people[1].name; people[1].rate;` and *not* `person`